# Openstack Identity extension v2 API missing

Tags: openstack, keystone

We have installed openstack on Centos as per the procedures here...

http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/yum/content/index.html

I've been trying to access the administrative end points to list users (and then add users and tenants)

However the administrative extensions don't seem to be available as when I do a GET to...

```
http://horizonip:5000/v2.0/users
```

I get...

```
<error message="The resource could not be found." code="404" title="Not Found"/>
```

and when I do...

```
http://horizonip:5000/v2.0/extensions
```

I get...

```
<extensions>
  <extension updated="2013-12-17T12:00:0-00:00" name="OpenStack Federation APIs" namespace="http://docs.openstack.org/identity/api/ext/OS-FEDERATION/v1.0" alias="OS-FEDERATION">
    <links>
      <link href="https://github.com/openstack/identity-api" type="text/html" rel="describedby"/>
    </links>
    <description>OpenStack Identity Providers Mechanism.</description>
  </extension>
  <extension updated="2013-07-07T12:00:0-00:00" name="OpenStack Keystone User CRUD" namespace="http://docs.openstack.org/identity/api/ext/OS-KSCRUD/v1.0" alias="OS-KSCRUD">
    <links>
      <link href="https://github.com/openstack/identity-api" type="text/html" rel="describedby"/>
    </links>
    <description>OpenStack extensions to Keystone v2.0 API enabling User Operations.</description>
  </extension>
  <extension updated="2013-07-07T12:00:0-00:00" name="OpenStack EC2 API" namespace="http://docs.openstack.org/identity/api/ext/OS-EC2/v1.0" alias="OS-EC2">
    <links>
      <link href="https://github.com/openstack/identity-api" type="text/html" rel="describedby"/>
    </links>
    <description>OpenStack EC2 Credentials backend.</description>
  </extension>
  <extension updated="2014-01-20T12:00:0-00:00" name="OpenStack Simple Certificate API" namespace="http://docs.openstack.org/identity/api/ext/OS-SIMPLE-CERT/v1.0" alias="OS-SIMPLE-CERT">
    <links>
      <link href="https://github.com/openstack/identity-api" type="text/html" rel="describedby"/>
    </links>
    <description>OpenStack simple certificate retrieval extension</description>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

I can't find any documentation on this side of things but I've been routing around and have found a folder admin_crud on the server which may have what's needed but I have no idea what to put in keystone.conf

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that these are inbuilt extensions and don't appear in the output from...

```
http://horizonip:5000/v2.0/extensions
```

All the administrative extensions are accessed through a different port, the default is 35357 but may be different and can be checked in the keystone.conf file by searching for admin_port.

Just use...

```
http://horizonip:admin_port/
```

as the base url for any administrative api calls.